# Can servlet's doGet method returns value back to java class?

Tags: java, servlets

I am calling servlet from simple java class. The servlet doGet method is getting called properly and some logic is written in doGet to get the result as String.

Can I return that string from servlet's doGet method back to calling function from simple java class? If possible, could you please provide the example?

Any help is aprreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is the ContactServlet simple java class which call the servlet:-

public class ContactServlet {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     String param = "username=YOURSTRING";
        String request = "http://localhost:8080/TestServlet/post";
        URL url = new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        url.openConnection();          
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +  Integer.toString(param.getBytes().length));
        connection.setUseCaches (false);

        System.out.println(connection);
        System.out.println(param);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
        out.writeBytes(param);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        for(int i=1;i<=8;i++){  
            System.out.println(connection.getHeaderFieldKey(i)+" = "+connection.getHeaderField(i));  
            }  

        connection.disconnect();



}
```

}

Below is servlets doGet method:-

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String username = request.getParameter( _USERNAME );
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("");
    out.println("");
    out.println("HelloWorld");
    out.println("");
    out.println("");
    out.println("");
    out.println("Hello " + username + "!");
    out.println("");
    out.println("");
}
```

Instead of writing it to web page, I want the String "Hello Username!" to be returned to ContactServlet class. How can we do that??

Comment: post your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet methods are meant to be called by the servlet container, not manually by the programmer),
 so you should not be calling `doPost()` or `doGet()` methods by yourself, rather you need a servlet container which will handle those methods for you.

In summary, you need to deploy your Servlet in a Servlet container like Tomcat, Jetty, etc. and when you make `HttpURLConnection` call, then
 the container delegates the call to the respective Servlet's `doPost()` or `doGet()` method.

What happens is that under the hood is that the Servlet container is responsible for instantiating the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects and then it delegates the request to the respective servlet methods.

Comment: Please have a look at code I have provided. I am just calling the url n container calls the servlet method for me. I just want the string back from servlet to java class.